# Cant select item after use android:inputType textMultiLine

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native, android-widget

I was trying to change Picker default settings to android , So I was changing android default settings  (since it can't be doned with css).

My problem is: Large strings wasnt showed by picker. So I make this changes at my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>   
    <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>

</style>
```

With this done, picker now wrap lines. But it isnt selectable anymore. I've tried to use android:clickable true, but hasnt worked.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Override `getDropDownView()` method in `ArrayAdapter` and put `setSingleLine(false)` in post method of view. So when view completely created it wraps the text to appropriate lines.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new TextView(_context);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView;
    item.setText("asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");
    final TextView finalItem = item;
    item.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalItem.setSingleLine(false);
        }
    });
    return item;
}
```